# error when call the unmanaged resouce functions from c#.net core dll into vb.netcore windows application

Tags: c#, vb.net, .net-core, unmanaged

I got Issues when I call unmanaged resource functions from C#.net core DLL into VB.net core windows application. The program execution just stops suddenly when the function is hit.

Please below is my code

**DLL Unmanaged function**

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

namespace TestLibrary1
{
  public class Class1
  {
    [UnmanagedCallersOnlyAttribute]
    public static IntPtr AddNE(IntPtr a)
    {
      try
      {
        IntPtr add = a;
        return add;
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + ex.Message);
      }
      return (IntPtr)0;
    }
  }
}
```

**VB.netcore windows code below to call dll**

```vb
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.Data

Public Class Form1
  Private Const DllName As String = "TestLibrary1NE.dll"

  <DllImport(DllName)>
  Private Shared Function AddNE(ByVal a As IntPtr) As IntPtr
  End Function
  Private Sub btnSend_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSend.Click
    Try
      Dim ptrAddress As IntPtr = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(txtAddress.Text.Trim())
      Dim ptrResponse As IntPtr = AddNE(ptrAddress)
      Dim strResponse As String = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(ptrResponse)
      MessageBox.Show(strResponse)
    Catch ex As EntryPointNotFoundException
      Console.WriteLine(e.ToString())
    End Try
    End
  End Sub
End Class
```

When the function `AddNE` (from the C# DLL) above is hit it suddenly stops the execution from nowhere.

May I know what is the solution to fix this and how to find out the error?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please, paste the error you're getting as well so other users can help you.

Answer (score 0):

It's not mentioned in the question but the code uses the [DNNE package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DNNE) to create a native library that exports all marked functions with the attribute `UnmanagedCallersOnly`.

The [DNNE package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DNNE) needs that 3 files be distributed together:

1. The managed assembly (`TestLibrary1.dll`);
2. The native assembly (`TestLibrary1NE.dll`);
3. And the `TestLibrary1.runtimeconfig.json`.

The catch is that both managed assembly (`TestLibrary1.dll`) and native assembly (`TestLibrary1NE.dll`) should be distributed together. And not only that but also the `TestLibrary1.runtimeconfig.json`. This is because the native assembly calls the managed assembly internally so all the files should be on the same path.

DNNE needs on Windows the `--runtime` flag or MSBuild [`RuntimeIdentifier`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/msbuild-props#runtimeidentifier) property to be set as target `win-x86` or `win-x64`, and both projects should be the same. Check the [3rd bullet here in the docs](https://github.com/AaronRobinsonMSFT/DNNE#generating-a-native-binary-using-the-dnne-nupkg).

Also, the project that uses `TestLibrary1.dll` should reference the project. Something like the following:

```xml
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\TestLibrary1\TestLibrary1.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

The changes to the C# project configuration file (`TestLibrary1.csproj`) are commented on below. `EnableDynamicLoading` should be `true` to generate the `TestLibrary1.runtimeconfig.json`. And DNNE needs both `PlatformTarget` and `RuntimeIdentifier` to be defined as `x64` and `win-x64` respectively.

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <RootNamespace>c_sharp</RootNamespace>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>

    <!-- Include the line below to generate the runtimeconfig.json -->
    <EnableDynamicLoading>true</EnableDynamicLoading>

    <!-- DNNE package asks to include those 2 also -->
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>

  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="DNNE" Version="1.0.32" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: but this is working in c#.netcore windows client when we call unmanaged function with UnmanagedCallersOnlyAttribute from dll.only the issue is comming into vb.netcore windows client and its simply stops the execution without throwing any error

Comment: Looks like something is missing in the question's code. If I try it and run the VB.NET program it shows me the error: `System.EntryPointNotFoundException: Unable to find an entry point named 'AddNE' in DLL 'TestLibrary1NE.dll'.`. Also, I've noticed that in the VB.NET code the `DllImport` should be inside a class to be marked as `Shared`. Would you please review the code and let me know? BTW, I'm using .NET 6.0

Comment: Please use below code to fix entry point exception then will see original issue what i have faced
    
        <DllImport("TestLibrary1NE.dll", EntryPoint:="AddNE")>
        Private Shared Function AddNE(ByVal a As IntPtr) As IntPtr
        End Function

Comment: Still no go for me. I've pushed the code I'm testing to this repository: https://github.com/lepsch/unmanaged-code If you try it, it fails with the error I've pointed out. Or maybe you can create a repository yourself and share with me.

Comment: Please add DNNE reference in dll code and build dll and it will generate TestLibrary1NE.Please look into below screen which i created DLL solution with reference DNNE

Comment: This [DNNE package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DNNE) is pretty interesting! Anyway, I've figured it out. You need to copy both generated DLLs (`TestLibrary1.dll` and `TestLibrary1NE.dll`) and also the `TestLibrary1.runtimeconfig.json` configuration to use in the VB.NET project.

Comment: I've edited my answer with this solution. Please, take a look.

Comment: Hi Lepsch, Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: Yes.  Check out the answer itself.

Comment: can you please post solution here because if i add DNNE package and add two testLibrary1.dll and TestLibrary1NE.sll also getting issue. Other than above what i missed here to run the code and how to generate this TestLibrary1.runtimeconfig.json

Comment: and also two dlls in same path in client bin folder i kept it and still got same issue for me.so please post solution here i just want to see what i missed it,Thanks for your help

Comment: Oh, I've completely forgotten to include how to generate the `runtimeconfig.json`. I've updated the answer with it. Please take a look.

Comment: @Raj, if this answer actually solved your problem please accept it so others would know the answer is right.

Comment: Nice. Good to know! Besides accepting it ✅, you can also upvote ▲ it if you like.

Comment: Hi lepsch
I faced one more issue related to above.if i want to call grpc functions from dll, i am facing same issue like execution stops

Comment: I just added grpc.aspnetcore dll in c# dll code and written one grpc function [UnmanagedCallersOnlyAttribute] public static void GetGrpcaddressNE(IntPtr ptrAddress) { try { string strAddress = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(ptrAddress);

            channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress(strAddress);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            WriteLog("ExceptionLog.txt" + ex.Message);
        }
    }

Comment: and trying to call above function from vb.netcore windows application client.but still got old issue like execution stops.i thought this issue is coming when i add grpc.aspnetcore dll in dll code

Comment: Let me check what's going on.

Comment: You have to include the GRPC DLLs together with the `TestLibrary1` DLLs you already have. Mainly the `Grpc.Core.Api.dll` and `Grpc.Net.Client.dll` and maybe the others too.

Comment: yes,i have included Grpc.Core.Api.dll and Grpc.Net.Client.dll already but the issue with Grpc.AspNetCore.dll when i add this Grpc.AspNetCore.dll the issue is coming.if i dont include that dll then i am able to call functions from dll.but i need to include Grpc.AspNetCore.dll into my project

Comment: Hi  lepsch, Any solution for above?

Comment: Would you please provide a repository with the entire code (if possible)? I've tested adding `AspNetCore` dependency and it works on my side.

Comment: It could be just a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).